# How to get a last record when using group by in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

This is my table  "AuctionDetails"

[image: auction]

The following select:

```
select string_agg("AuctionNO",',' ) as  "AuctionNO"
      ,sum("QuntityInAuction" ) as "QuntityInAuction"
      ,"AmmanatPattiID"
      ,"EntryPassDetailsId" 
      ,"BrokerID"
      ,"TraderID"
      ,"IsSold"
      ,"IsActive"
      ,"IsExit"
      ,"IsNew"
      ,"CreationDate"
from "AuctionDetails"
group by "AmmanatPattiID"
        ,"EntryPassDetailsId"  
        ,"TraderID"
        ,"IsSold"
        ,"IsActive"
        ,"IsExit"
        ,"IsNew"
        ,"BrokerID"
        ,"CreationDate"
```

gives me this result:

[image: here is my result]

but i need record like

```
AuctionNo                                QunatityInAuction  AmmanatpattiID  EntryPassDetailID  BrokerID  Trader ID  IsSold  ISActive  ISExit  IsNew  CreationDate
AU8797897,AU8797886,AU596220196F37379    1050               -1               228,229            42         42         f         t       f      t      2013-10-10
```

At the end i need a latest entry of trader and broker which is in our case "42", sum of quantity , and concatenation of auction number ...

Comment: "Latest" is defined by `CreationDate`? Still missing pk definition and Postgres version (run `SELECT version()`). Both relevant for the query.

Comment: "AuctionID" is my Primary key.

Comment: Version is "PostgreSQL 9.0.12, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 32-bit"

Comment: latest record can be identified by primary key... in our case latest records is record number 3 with AuctionID=137

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. Combinations of aggregate and window functions or a combination of window functions and `DISTINCT` ...

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM  (
   SELECT string_agg("AuctionNO", ',') AS  "AuctionNO"
         ,sum("QuntityInAuction") AS "QuntityInAuction"
   FROM   "AuctionDetails"
   ) a
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT "AmmanatPattiID"
         ,"EntryPassDetailsId" 
         ,"BrokerID"
         ,"TraderID"
         ,"IsSold"
         ,"IsActive"
         ,"IsExit"
         ,"IsNew"
         ,"CreationDate"
   FROM   "AuctionDetails"
   ORDER  BY "AuctionID" DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) b
```

For the simple case of a single result row for a whole table, this may be simplest.

Comment: it is not a proper solution .....i need a last entry of broker and trader which is in our case second record..

Comment: @AijazChauhan: "Last" according to what sort order? Please *edit* your question and provide a proper definition. Also a table definition (including primary key) and your version of Postgres

Answer (score 3):

The Postgres wiki describes how to define your own FIRST and LAST aggregate functions.  For example:

```
-- Create a function that always returns the last non-NULL item
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.last_agg ( anyelement, anyelement )
RETURNS anyelement LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT AS $$
        SELECT $2;
$$;

-- And then wrap an aggregate around it
CREATE AGGREGATE public.LAST (
        sfunc    = public.last_agg,
        basetype = anyelement,
        stype    = anyelement
);
```

The page is here:  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)